# Show that a group of order $2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 23^r$ is solvable but not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups, simple-groups, solvable-groups

**Let $G$ be a group of order $2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 23^r$ where $r \gt 0$**

**a) Show that $G$ is not simple.**

**b) Show that $G$ is solvable.**

My attempt:

a) Assume that:

$S$ is the set of sylow-$23$-subgroups and $n_{23}$ is the number of conjugates of $S$

By Sylow's 3rd theorem, we have

$n_{23} | 2^2 \cdot 5$ and $n_{23}\equiv 1 \pmod {23}$

Which implies that $n_{23}=1,\ 2^a,\ 5,\ 2^b \cdot 5$ where $a,b\leq 2$, and $n_{23}=1+23k$

Since $23>2^a,\ 5,\ 2^b.5$, if we assume that $n_{23}= 2^a,\ 5, $ or $2^b \cdot 5$, that would lead us to a contradiction. Hence, $n_{23}=1$, and then $S$ is normal.

As a result, $G$ is not simple.

b) $S$ is a $23$-group $\implies S$ is nilpotent $\implies S$ is solvable.

Since $S$ is normal, $G/S$ is a group. We have

$o(G/S)=23$ $\implies G/S$ is cyclic $\implies G/S$ is abelian $\implies G/S$ is solvable $\implies G$ is solvable.

Edit:

$S$ is a $23$-group $\implies S$ is nilpotent $\implies S$ is solvable.

Since $S$ is normal, $G/S$ is a group. We have

$o(G/S)=2^2 \cdot 5$

Suppose that $G/S=H$.

We have $o(H)=2^2 \cdot 5$

Suppose that

$R$ is the set of Sylow-${5}$-subgroups and $n_{5}$ is the number of conjugates of $R$

From the 3rd Sylow's theorem, we have

$n_5\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $n_5 | 2^2$

which implies that

$n_5=1+5k$ and $n_5=1,\ 2,$ or $2^2$.

Since $5>\gt 2,\ 2^2$, the only possible value of $n_5$ is $1$. So we can conclude that $R$ is normal in $H$.

$R$ is a $5$-group $\implies R$ is nilpotent $\implies R$ is solvable.

Since $R$ is normal, $H/R$ is a group. We have

$o(H/R)=4$ $\implies H/R$ is abelian $\implies H/R$ is solvable $\implies H=G/S$ is solvable  $\implies G$ is solvable.

Comment: Why does $o(G/S)=23$?

Comment: @user10354138 sorry I meant $o(G/S)=2^2.5$.

Comment: It's no longer true that $G/S$ is necessarily cyclic now that the order has been corrected.  Part (a) is correct, though.

Comment: @JohnSamples Right, I was thinking of that too. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnSamples I edited it. Do you mind looking to my edits? Thank you

Comment: Looks good!  Maybe there is a quicker way, tho.

Comment: @JohnSamples Thank you! really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G/S$ must be normal because $n_5(G/S)=1, 2, \text{or } 4$.